# C# - Create placeholder properties dynamically based on SortOrder of other properties

Tags: c#

using C# I want to create below table output (see sreenshot) where the columns with red background color need to be added dynamically.

Output:
[image: example]

I receive a list of attributes based on below class structure:

```
public class Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Order { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The part I struggle with is to create "dynamic" placeholder columns/properties for the output. Those columns need to be created based on the ***Order property*** of the existing attributes to fill the gaps so that the structure of the output does not change.

The name of the actual/existing attributes could be generic for the output.

Structure based on below screenshot:

- You can neglect Column A & B, they come from a different object
- column "Value1" == Order 4
- column "Value2" == Order 6

Because the ***first*** ***existing*** attribute has an order of **4**, *three columns* need to be prepended (starting with 1).
Because the second attribute has an order of 6, one column needs to be added inbetween to fill the gap.
The rest of the columns should be created up until a predefined column number.

I hope this makes sense, if not feel free to ask for more details. In reality the structure is more complex but it should work with this simplified example.

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate place holder attributes for all order-values you could do something like this:

```
var attributesByOrder = myAttributes.ToDictionary(a => a.Order, a => a);
var maxOrder = myAttributes.Max(a => a.Order);
var attributesAndPlaceholders = Enumerable.Range(1, maxOrder).Select(i => 
         attributesByOrder.TryGet(i, out var a) ? 
                    a : 
                    new Attribute{
                           Name ="PlaceHolder",
                           Order = i,
                           Value = ""
                           });
```

This will use the existing attribute if that exists for a specific order value, or generate a placeholder attribute if not. This assumes all attributes has actual order values, and that they are unique.

Comment: Fantastic. This works beautifully.